# Install MonoDevelop IDE for Redhat Linux

Tags: linux, mono, ide, monodevelop, redhat

I am trying to install and configure MonoDevelop on my Oracle VM Virtual Box. The Operating System that  running on the VM is RedHat Linux.

With the help of the below link, I have installed the mono-2.10.8 and also I was able to compile and run the sample c# source code on Linux through the shell.

[Here](http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx)

Now, I am trying to install or configure the IDE, please advise me for the good IDEs.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Monodeveloper from the below link. I chose the Operating System as CentOS

[MonoDevelop](http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home%3atpokorra%3amono&package=monodevelop-opt)

Answer (score 0):

This will also install mono-opt from the home:tpokorra repo

mono-opt is the latest stable version (3.6) on mono available from [Mono Project](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)

I found this way much easier for installing mono on redhat / centos 6